# How can one site's security keep another site from loading?

Tags: security

My company provides third-party customer service for a Big Communications Company (hereafter BCC). Our employees must log in to BCC's site to help customers. I have also created some intranet resources for them to use.

**If they are signed in to BCC's site, my intranet site will not load** in another tab or window - it says "Internet Explorer cannot display the web page, most likely causes: you are not connected to the internet..." etc.

**What's going on here? Can I fix it?**

Here are as many details as I think may be relevant:

### BCC Site

- Requires IE
- Before a user can access it, they must install a certificate on their machine, issued to them personally
- Has agonizing sign-in process that freaks out our antivirus software:

  - **Popup** - choose a certificate
  - **Popup** - "An application is requesting access to a Protected Item - CryptoAPI Private Key - OK"
  - **Sign in** with username and password
  - **Click** on one of two links
  - **Message** - "This website wants to run the following add-on: 'SSL VPN Relay Loader' from 'Cisco Systems, Inc (Unverified Publisher)'. If you trust the website and the add-on and want to allow it to run, click here..." (and simultaneous pop-up like the previous one).
  - **Popup** - "The applications digital signature has an error. Do you want to run the application? Name: jpimp. Publisher:Cisco Systems, Inc. From (URL listed)."
  - **Antivirus software warns** "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe "process is trying to inject into another process. This behavior is typical of some malicious programs." Terminate, Deny, or Skip. - SKIP"
  - **Sign in** with another username and password
  - **Popup** - "This page contains bot secure and nonsecure items. Do you want to display the nonsecure items? - Yes, No, More Info - YES"
- Appears to be Java Server Pages. Uses lots of frames. Disables right-click with JavaScript.

### Intranet site

- PHP and login-based, but a simple "hello world" HTML page fails the same
- Running on Apache on a Windows Server machine; using port 88 to avoid conflict with IIS

### Known workarounds

- **Visit the intranet on localhost**. It will load when the server copy won't. It makes no difference whether localhost uses port 80 or 88. (Obviously this only helps me.)
- **Open FireFox** for the Intranet site (not all users have this option currently)
- **Open a new copy of IE** from the Start menu and load the Intranet site there. This works, even though it looks identical to opening a new window from an existing IE instance, which fails.

Is the BCC site somehow hijacking IE's DNS? Is localhost exempt from that?

Comment: Voting for moving this question to serverfault.com. (At first I thought superuser.com would be the right place, but after looking the descriptions for both sites, I think serverfault is more appropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the "SSL VPN Relay Loader" actually starts some kind of VPN in that IE session and thus you are not on able to reach your intranet anymore.

Comment: Sounds plausible. If that's what they're doing, does it seem odd to you?

Comment: Certainly odd and almost unheard of. Are you sure it's just Java Server Pages and not some kind of applet or local Java application? Sounds like you're in no mood to ask BCC for help/documentation (and I do not blame you)?

Comment: This turned out to be correct. If I visit whatismyip.com in that browser window and another, they show different IPs. As far as that browser is concerned, it can't find local resources because it's not located on our network anymore. The only solution seems to be for our employees to use either an alternate browser or a separate copy of IE (from the start menu) to open our intranet.